# encapsulation issue with making an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Would anyone mind explaining to me why...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scu = ['0291285', '0409338', '0521704', '0521990', '0523652', '0523657', '0523660', '0523704'];
    var inData = $('#output');
    var testdiv = $('#testdiv');
    function Item(scu, description, price, extended, type) {
        this.scu = scu;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.extended = extended;
        this.type = type;
        //this.saved = function() {};
    }
    var rows = [];
    function get() {
        inData.html('');    
        $.each(scu, function(index, val) {
            $.post('chBuild.php', {scu:val}, function(output) {
                $.each(output, function(i, obj) { 
                    var i = 0;
                    rows[i] = new Item(obj.scu, obj.description, obj.price, obj.extended, obj.type);
                    console.log(rows[i].price)
                                    //this logs every object but...                 

                    i =+ 1;
                });
            }, 'json');         
        });
        console.log(rows[0].price);

            //this says rows[0] is undefined?

    }
    inData.click(get);
});
```

I am trying to find the best way to create and store multiple objects.

Comment: You shouldn't do `var i = 0` inside the `each`, this way every item will be assigned to position `0`. The last statement (`i += 1;`) is irrelevant, since that variable only exists inside that closure (i.e. every loop of the iteration would redefine `i`). Use the `i` provided as argument (`function(i,obj) {`), it will be accurate in your case.

Comment: @mgibsonbr is on the money, the extra `var i` is always going to be zero. Also remove the `i= +1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.post('chBuild.php', {scu:val}, function(output) {
            $.each(output, function(i, obj) { 
                var i = 0;
                rows[i] = new Item(obj.scu, obj.description, obj.price, obj.extended, obj.type);
                console.log(rows[i].price)
                i =+ 1;
            });
        }, 'json');
```

Here the call to $.post is asynchronous, is going to be filled just when the ajax call returns. Maybe you should make it synchronous

```
$.ajax({'url': 'chBuild.php', 'async': false, ...);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because `$.post` is asynchronous. The `each` only start the HTTP request, but it returns immediatly, so when the second `console.log` runs the item had not been created yet.

Comment: Is there a way to make it run only after `$.post`?

Comment: You mean, after all posts for all itens have run? You could make the requests synchronous as JoseP suggested. There might be other ways, but I can't answer that from the top of my head.